# Return contents of a URL as a file in a jaxRS response

Tags: response, jax-rs

I am a REST wrapper service and when I call the back end service, in some cases they have generated a file which I can retrieve with a particular URL: https://localhost:1234/...  How do I most efficiently use javax.ws.core.Response to send the contents at that link to the caller?  I can probably read the URL myself to a local file and send it that way, but am wondering if REST will do that for me.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

when your back-end url is public to your client, you can send redirect 301.

When it's not

```java
@Get
@Produces({...})
public Response readFile() {

    return Response.ok().entity(new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override public void write(OutputStream output)
           throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
           // open the back-end url and copy the bytes to given output
           final InputStream input = new URL(back-end-url).openStream();
           final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
           for (int read = -1; (read = input.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
               output.write(buf, 0, read);
           }
           output.flush();
        }
    }).build();
}
```